# How to set the coordinates of a JButton in Blue J?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set the coordinates of a Jbutton in Blue J, I've tried button.setbounds but it says that doesn't exist. This is what I have so far:

```
  public void makeButtons()
{   
    // create buttons
   buttonL1 = new JButton( "Button L1" ); 
   add( buttonL1);
   buttonL1.setbounds( 220, 180, (int) rHeight, (int) rWidth );
   buttonL2 = new JButton( "Button L2" ); 
   add( buttonL2 );
   buttonR3 = new JButton( "Button R3" ); 
   c.add( buttonR3 );
   buttonR4 = new JButton( "Button R4" ); 
   c.add( buttonR4 );

   ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
   buttonL1.addActionListener( handler );
   buttonL2.addActionListener( handler ); 
   buttonR3.addActionListener( handler );
   buttonR4.addActionListener( handler ); 
   c.repaint();
}



/**
 * Button Event Handling
 */
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
        "You pressed: " + e.getActionCommand() );
  }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is don't. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for a better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the `setbounds` doesn't exist, but the `setBounds(...)` in fact does -- capitalization matters as does the skill of looking this up in the API. But having said that, don't use `null` layouts or `setBounds(...)` as that leads to the creation of rigid GUI's that *may* look good on one computer using that OS and screen resolution, but will look terrible everywhere else, will create JPanels that don't function in JScrollPanes, and lead to inflexible GUI's that are royal witch to debug or enhance.  Instead use the layout managers to help you place components.

Also note that your question has nothing to do with BlueJ, which is nothing more than the IDE tool you're using to create the program with, and all to do with Java and Swing.

Comment: @JL9: again **don't** use setBounds. It marks your program as a newbie nightmare program and will bite you in the end.

Comment: @immibis: this is or should be a family-friendly site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that may be so, but "royal witch to debug" is meaningless.